# Batch Script Iterative form

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script which :

1. check the files in a directory and check if it exists in another
   directory and it should not exists there
2. count each file with a specific format, there should be just one of each

if both of the above statement is true then generate a success file.

Below is my code which is working fine:

```
SET /A file1=file2=Val=0
SET /A FileE=1
set /a flagname=1

for %%A in (*ABC*.txt) do set /a file1+=1
for %%A in (*XYZ*.txt) do set /a file2+=1

for %%i in ("*") do if exist "Processed\%%~nxi" SET /A FileE=0

SET /A Val=%file1%*%file2%*%FileE% 

if %Val% EQU 1 (
echo SUCESS>Sucess.txt 
SET Flag=Sucess
echo %Flag%) else (

if %file1% EQU 0 ( echo Missing ABC.txt files >> Error.txt) 
if %file1% GTR 1 ( echo More than 1 ABC.txt files >> Error.txt) 

if %file2% EQU 0 ( echo Missing XYZ.txt files >> Error.txt) 
if %file2% GTR 1 ( echo More than 1 XYZ.txt files >> Error.txt)

(for %%i in ("*") do if exist "Processed\%%~nxi" echo(File Exists in 
Processed 
Folder %%~i)>>Error.txt
SET Flag=FAILURE
echo %Flag%)
```

My problem is how to transform above code to iterate over a list of number of files like 100 ? Below is the code which I tried :

```
@echo off
setlocal enable delayed expansion
Set Filen[0]=ABC*.txt
Set Filen[1]=XYZ*.txt
SET /A Val=1 
SET /A File1=0

FOR /l %%G in (0,1,1) Do (
echo !Filen[%%G]! hi
set File1=0
echo %file1% Count
for %%A in (!Filen[%%G]! ) do (
set File1=!File1!+1
echo %%A %file1%)
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, could you please clarify! My initial assessment is that all you want for your first script is this: `@If Exist "Processed\" For %%A In ("*ABC*.txt" "*XYZ*.txt") Do @If Exist "Processed\%%A" (>>"error.txt" @Echo %%A) Else >>"success.txt" @Echo %%A`. The files in `error.txt` will be those that are duplicated in `.\Processed`, and those in `success.txt` would be those unique to the working directory, _i.e. not in `.\Processed`_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your search words in a string and iterate over it:

```
Set "Search=ABC DEF XYZ"
For %%A in (%Search%) do (
```

Or in a file and read one by one

```
For /f "usebackq" %%A in ("Search.txt") Do (
```

With this file Search.txt

```
ABC
DEF
XYZ
```

In the environment

```
> tree a:\ /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
A:\
└───Test
    │   ABC_123.txt
    │   DEF_456.txt
    │   Search.txt
    │
    └───Processed
```

The following batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\01\SO_51120147.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "BaseDir=A:\Test"
Set Err=^>^> "Error.txt" Call Echo=[%%date%% %%time%%] 
PushD "%BaseDir%" || (%Err% can't locate %BaseDir% & Pause &Goto :Eof)
%Err% Job %~f0 started by %USERNAME%
Set " Flag=Sucess"
:: Uncomment for string variant
:: Set "Search=ABC DEF XYZ"
:: For %%A in (%Search%) do (

:: use the file variant
For /f "usebackq" %%A in ("Search.txt") Do (
    Set Cnt=0
    For %%B in (%%A*.txt) Do Set /A Cnt=1
    if !Cnt! NEQ 1  (
      %Err% Count of %%A*.txt file=[!Cnt!]
      SET Flag=FAILURE
  )
)
For %%A in (*) do if exist "Processed\%%~nxA" (
    %Err% File %%A does exist in Processed Folder
  Set Flag=FAILURE
)
%Err% Job %~f0 terminated with %Flag%
```

Yields this output:

```
> type A:\Test\Error.txt
[2018-07-01 13:10:34,43]  Job Q:\Test\2018\07\01\SO_51120147.cmd started by LotPings
[2018-07-01 13:10:34,45]  Count of XYZ*.txt file=[0]
[2018-07-01 13:10:34,47]  Job Q:\Test\2018\07\01\SO_51120147.cmd terminated with FAILURE
```

---

**EDIT: Explanation of the somehow tricky line:**

```
Set Err=^>^> "Error.txt" Call Echo=[%%date%% %%time%%]
```

To not have to pre/append every line which should go to the error log with
the redirection and a (fixed) file name I put these together with the
echo command and a [date time] stamp into a variable.

To avoid immediate interpretation when setting the variable, the '>' have to 
be esaped with a caret, and to delay the expansion of the %-signs these have 
to be doubled. (otherwise each log entry had the same date time)

To force expansion of date time when echoing the (pseudo) call is neccessary.